# Changing Generated Hibernate Foreign key in @OnetoOne shared primary key scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-annotations

I am using Hibernate as my ORM in a JEE6 project run on a JBOSS Server with MySql database.
In my project for every Data element there will be detail element. And for this I have created a bidirectional one to one relationship with shared primary key as below.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="DATA", schema = "TEST")
    public class Data implements Serializable {
    ....
    .....
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "data", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public Details getDetails() {
            return details;
    ....
    }


@Entity
@Table(name = "DETAILS", schema = "TEST")
public class Details implements Serializable {
...
...
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = { @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "property", value = "data") })
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "DETAILS_ID", nullable=false)
    @Index(name="DETAILS_ID")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_DATA_ID")
    public Long getDetailsId() {
        return detailsId;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "DETAILS_ID", referencedColumnName = "DATA_ID")
    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }
...
}
```

Even after mentioning @ForeignKey it generates an ugly foreign key constraint like below

```
alter table TEST.DETAILS add constraint FK9FDD7BA22964C454 foreign key (DETAILS_ID) references TEST.DATA
```

How do I create a clean foreign key constraint in such scenario? I need to create a foreign key constraint with name 'FK_DATA_ID'.

Answer (score 3):

`@ForeignKey` has property `inverseName` which you can use here, as per document

> inverseName referencing to the other side constrain,

so you can use `@ForeignKey(name = "FK_DATA_ID", inverseName = "FK_DATA_INVRS_ID")`
 here is [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html)

**Update:**

There seems there was bug in hibernate, here is a [link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8783#comment-56911). From Hibernate version 4.3.1 it is resolved

Also they have deprecated [`org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ForeignKey.html) you need to use new [`javax.persistence.ForeignKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html)

Comment: Your link shows its a JEE7 implementation. I am using JEE6 and Hibernate does provide a annotation for @ForeignKey with inverName as a property but even that is not working. It still generates that ugly Hibernate Constraint.

Comment: which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: I am using the JBOSS AS 7.0 provided hibernate 4.0. Beta version

Comment: well in that case `@ForeignKey` won't work as hibernate has unresolved bug, check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with tables with JOINED inheritance. Try to **use deprecated @org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey** annotation. In many places it is still (hibernate 4.3.8) works better than one from javax.persistence package.

Then modern javax.persistence.ForeignKey doesn't work, my suggestion is to use it in conjunction with the deprecated org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey leaving helpful comment next to it:

```
// TODO remove when modern approach works as intended
```